# Publishing multiple mxd in one go

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, map-service

I tried to write a python code to publishing multiple mxd in one go, but it seems that not working with me. I experience is a little bit.
what might the wrong in my code and why it wasn't work with me:

```
import os
import arcpy

path= r"P:\Practical1_Administrators\Saved"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
  for fl in files:
     if fl.lower().endswith(".mxd"):
       mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(path, fl))
       print mxd.filePath
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py")
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(mxd)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"P:\Practical1_Administrators\Saved\Arabi_Buildings_IsraelTMGrid.mxd")
msd = r"C:\Project\Output\Project.msd"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "County Maps")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
del mxd, msd
msd = r"C:\Project\Project.msd"
arcpy.mapping.PublishMSDToServer (msd, "http://<MyServer>/arcgis/services", 
              "<MyServer>", "MyMapService", "MyMapServiceFolder", ["WMS", "KML"])
```

Comment: edit your code, indent 4 space for each line and it shows up as readable code

Comment: ... or highlight your code and click the format {} button.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not working"?  Is there an error or another symptom?

Comment: Based on your code above, nothing below `print mxd.filePath` is in the loop. That means the l last MXD it finds will go through the publish code. You need to "tab/indent" all the publish code into the loop

Comment: Also this line is so, so wrong `mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py")`

Answer (score 1):

Your script started out ok but then went a little astray after the loop.  Hopefully this gets you there, although I can't test as I don't have ArcGIS Server available right now.

```
import os
import arcpy

path= r"P:\Practical1_Administrators\Saved"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
    for fl in files:
        if fl.lower().endswith(".mxd"):
            flname = os.path.splitext(fl)[0]
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(path, fl))
            print mxd.filePath
            analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(mxd)
            msd = r"C:\Project\Output\Project_{}.msd".format(flname)
            df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "County Maps")[0]
            arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
            arcpy.mapping.PublishMSDToServer (msd, "http://<MyServer>/arcgis/services", "<MyServer>", "MyMapService", "MyMapServiceFolder", ["WMS", "KML"])
```

Please note, I haven't changed much in the code, just removed unneeded lines and corrected the indentation.